# How to create a JWT using ES256 in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jwt, google-app-engine-python, python-cryptography

I am working on a Google App Engine solution that needs to integrate with an API where the authentication is being done with JWT. The encryption algorithm to be used is ES256, but every time I try to call the `jwt.encode()` method with ES256, the following error gets thrown:

`ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time`

This is happening because cryptography.io is not supported on App Engine (standard env) as it uses CFFI (C Foreign Function Interface).

Are there any other recommended approaches to create this JWT from my Python App Engine app and using ES256?

Here's the simplified code:

```
import jwt

keystring = """-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
SECRET
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"""

HEADERS = {'alg': 'ES256', 'kid': '1234SECRET', 'typ': 'JWT'}
PAYLOAD = {
    'iss': 'secret-secret-secret',
    'exp': time.time() + 20 * 60,
    'aud': 'audience'
}

key = jwt.encode(PAYLOAD, keystring, algorithm='ES256', headers=HEADERS)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use the [App Engine Standard Second-Generation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/) runtime instead? It should support any dependency that uses the CFFI.

Comment: Hey @DustinIngram, sadly the app is built on Python27 and it's not in the scope to migrate it. So I guess I can't use the standard environment V2. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not the most ideal situation, but you could create a small Python 3 app (possibly even a Cloud Function) which generates the token, which you could call from the Python 2 app.

Comment: I was thinking about that as well. Maybe creating a service within my project using the `env: flex` configuration and provide an API to call it. That should work right?

Comment: Yep, I believe it would.

Comment: I'm curious if you ever found a workaround.  I'm facing the same issue